# Splice() function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript using splice() function but I'm not able to delete the target element.

```
    var a = [];
    a.push("cs");
    a.push("ac");
    var curr2 = a.indexOf("ac");
    if(curr2 != -1){
        a = a.splice(curr2,1);
    } 
    console.log(a);
```

Expected result : ["cs"] Actual Result : ["ac"]

Can someone explain this behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: I have the understanding that `splice()` affects your array and don't need to assing it's result to the same array, because if you do you are assigning the removed value to your array, in your second example remove the part `a= ` and you'll see what I mean, and your first example gives ["2"] not ["1"] https://jsfiddle.net/lixusrarnavo/166ug1tk/

Comment: got it. Thanks!!!

Comment: It works as expected, by **you** are expecting the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because Splice return the elements that you removed.

Remember that Splice modifies the original Array so when you make

```
a = a.splice(curr2,1);
```

You are storing the elements removed.

Replace that line with

```
a.splice(curr2,1);
```

And that should solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You code is pulling 1 element from the array starting at index 1:

```js
var a = [];
a.push("cs");
a.push("ac");
var curr2 = a.indexOf("ac");
console.log("curr2 = " + curr2);
// curr2 = 1;
if (curr2 != -1) {
    var b = a.slice();
    b.splice(curr2, 1);
    console.log(b);
    // ["ac"]
    var c = a.slice();
    c.splice(1, 1);
    console.log(c);
    // ["ac"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`splice` returns the item you have deleted in a array. In short, change `a = a.splice(curr2,1);` to `a.splice(curr2,1);` and your code will work as expected. Since `splice` modifies the array you will get an array without the desired element. Where as before you were reassigning a to the return value of `splice`